What is the engine power and brake configurations when starting takeoff?
When taxiing from the gate to the runway, there is a near-constant engine sound and a near-constant speed (at least from my perspective as a passenger). Once we get to the runway and align for takeoff, the engine sound reduces to near-zero and we are not moving.
Now, while starting to takeoff, I have often noticed that the engine sound increases significantly (much more than the sound levels during taxi), but the plane does not appear to move for a few seconds. And then all of a sudden, we start moving. I had assumed my mind was simply not registering the movement, but I flew on a A350 (taking off from ORY runway 07) a few days ago with a live tail camera feed and it was quite obvious during those few seconds that we really were not moving.
I found this video where the pilot of an A350 appears to hold on to the brakes while increasing engine power and then releasing it to start takeoff.
Why is this done? My guess is that the pilot does not want to lose those few tens of meters accelerating with lower engine power, but I can't imagine that would really be a problem. In fact, wouldn't this lead to more wear and tear of the brakes? And the runway length is 3320m while an A350 needs 2600m, giving it what appears to be plenty of room.

FYI, holding the brakes doesn't cause wear and tear.  They only wear down if applied while the wheels are rotating.

This is for equalizing the engine N1 RPM if there is any discrepancy between them.
So, a plane's jet engine "spools up" before takeoff and holds at a specific thrust level to ensure all engines reach a consistent power level simultaneously, preventing uneven thrust during acceleration which could lead to loss of control during takeoff.

Why pilots should set thrust in two steps for takeoff?
The stabilization step ensures that all engines reach a rotation speed value from
where the increase of engine thrust will be almost identical to each other (as shown in figure below).

The N1/EPR/THR stabilization value is defined during flight test campaign
for every engine type with collaboration from engine manufacturers.

Example on how it's done
Airbus A310:

Slightly advance throttles and monitor spool-up
until both engine are above idle (approx 40% N1)
or
Slightly advance throttles and monitor spool-up
until both engine are aligned and stabilized
between 1.05 and 1.10 EPR with no more than
0.002 EPR difference between both engines.


About your question about takeoff conditions... during takeoff usually it is never so on the edge that a pilot would want to not lose a few meters of the runway accelerating at a lower thrust.
In fact, most of the takeoffs are done with a lowered than maximum thrust which takes advantage of the fact that most runways are very long and planes have more than enough thrust to takeoff without using the full runway or the full thrust.
This is called Flex Temp in Airbus and Reduced take-off thrust in Boeing.

EPR = Engine Pressure Ratio is the ratio of the turbine exit pressure to the engine intake pressure
N1 = Speed of the low pressure spool and serves as the primary power setting, and N2 is the speed of the high pressure spool
